# SwipeRefreshLayout not working on android version 22 and down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

Good day everyone , I want to ask why I can't  create SwipeRefresh on    RecycleView. It works fine on Marshmallow only , it destroys the app in another version  here is [Screenshot of logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0el4AZQaRJtWElCZzYtSzlSZ2c/view?usp=sharing)
[image: Image below]

Comment: Could you show us your error log?

Comment: post your whole logcat

Comment: Here is [Screenshot logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0el4AZQaRJtWElCZzYtSzlSZ2c/view?usp=sharing)
sorry for late .

Comment: Now we could really use some code to refer to with this error :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logcat:

- You're using native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`)
- On Marshmallow fragments are slightly more complex and introduced `getContext()` method, which is not present on earlier platforms.
- I don't know of any practical case where `getContext()` returns a different thing from `getActivity()`.

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`.

It's worth noting that this has nothing to do with the `SwipeRefreshLayout` itself. You just used wrong method call in the `OnRefreshListener` callback.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help now it's work correctly .

Comment: @EugenPechanec please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible